# Sitecore glassmapper how to fetch the datasource from the rendering

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc, glass-mapper

need an suggestion on Sitecore rendering where i want to use glassmodel to render the item.

I have a page and that has many renderings and each renderings has data source associated with it.

I know that below statement will give me the Current context, not the datasource item.

```
var context = new SitecoreContext();
            Model = context.GetCurrentItem<HomePage>();
```

What is the best option to solve my query? I gave gone through [this](https://rajaniamit.wordpress.com/2016/04/11/get-datasource-item-in-sitecore-mvc-controller-rendering/) article. But i'm really not convinced with that method as i'm using IoC (Windsor Castle) and have to write Unit test cases for each method. I may have to mock these objects later. I'm looking for the approach where i will be using Interface not the class.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your controller is derived from `GlassController` you can use `GetDataSourceItem<I..>()`. That will give you the datasource.

**Please note:** Glassmapper is now absolute. This class will be removed in Future Releases. CS0618 Warning.

Comment: This exactly  what i was looking for. Thanks @Gatogordo

Answer (score 2):

If you using Glass Mapper 5, the documentation doesn't refer to using GlassController anymore.  You can use IMvcContext like below:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc;

public class TitlesController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IMvcContext mvcContext = new MvcContext();

        // will return the DatasourceItem if set, otherwise the page context is returned
        Titles model = mvcContext.GetRenderingItem<Titles>();

        Titles dsModel = mvcContext.GetDataSourceItem<Titles>();

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Gatogorodo's answer

if you controller is derived from GlassController or if you are in GlassView you can use `this.DatasourceItem` to get the data source.

`this.GetDataSourceItem<Model>()` will get you the desired model which might be one of the base template for the item template.